# LAP algorithm not working with large numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

## include

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

long int lenghtOfLongestAP(long int set[],long int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)  return n;

    long int L[n][n];
    long int llap = 2;

    for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        L[i][n-1] = 2;

    for (long int j=n-2; j>=1; j--)
    {

        int i = j-1, k = j+1;
        while (i >= 0 && k <= n-1)
        {
           if (set[i] + set[k] < 2*set[j])
               k++;

           else if (set[i] + set[k] > 2*set[j])
           {   L[i][j] = 2, i--;   }

           else
           {
               L[i][j] = L[j][k] + 1;

               llap = max(llap, L[i][j]);

               i--; k++;
           }
        }
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            L[i][j] = 2;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return llap;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream cout("Output.txt");
    ifstream cin("cablecar-sub4-attempt3.txt");
    int ab;
    cin >> ab;
    for (long int z = 0; z < ab; z++)
    {
        long int bs;
        cin >> bs;
        long int array[bs];
        for(long int h = 0; h<bs; h++)
            cin >> array[h];
        sort(array, array + bs);
        cout << "Case #" << z+1 << ": " << lenghtOfLongestAP(array, bs) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. It is a LAP (Largest arithmetic progression) algorithm, so it finds the largest progression in an sorted array. I have the following set of data:

[pastebin.com/77meKfKW](http://pastebin.com/77meKfKW)

Strangely, the program crashes after case 30, which it shouldn't. What kind of problem might it be and how can I fix it?

Comment: Crashes where?  How?  The more debug information you can supply the better.

Comment: @J... According to my print tests, I believe it to be here:     for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        L[i][n-1] = 2;

Comment: @J... Also case 30 as i said

Comment: Please reason for downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I would guess it is because there is a lot of lacking information here that you could easily provide.  Use a debugger - it should be easy to isolate which line the crash occurs on.  It should also be easy to provide the reason for the crash (what is the exact error that causes the crash?).  Be clear about what "case 30" means - a debugger can allow you to inspect the values at runtime.  Otherwise, someone has to run your code and do the debugging work for you.  That's often a lot to ask.

Comment: @J... The bug happens exactly at the creation of  long int L[n][n]; with a value of 267 for n. I believe it is memory allocation; I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stack overflow.  You are allocating your array on the stack with 267*267 entries which uses a lot of memory.

Try allocating the memory on the heap instead, or simply changing the array from being local to being global (with a fixed maximum value of n).

e.g.

change

```
long int lenghtOfLongestAP(long int set[],long int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)  return n;

    long int L[n][n];
```

to

```
long int L[1000][1000]; // or whatever your maximum n might be
long int lenghtOfLongestAP(long int set[],long int n)
{
    if (n <= 2)  return n;
```